# Method too large: com/tndgl/ogzjx284034/MraidView.<clinit> ()V

Tags: java, android-studio

after I migrate my project to Androidx
when i build my project it gives me this error

**Method too large: com/tndgl/ogzjx284034/MraidView. ()V**
what does it mean??
how can I resolve it?

### dependencies

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation files('libs/com-tndgl-ogzjx284034.jar')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
    implementation 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
    implementation 'com.memetix:microsoft-translator-java-api:0.6.2'
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.0.7'
    implementation 'cn.carbs.android:AutoZoomInImageView:1.0.1'
```

Comment: The `<clinit>` method is a special method that performs class initialization.  So this compilation error means that `MraidView` class has class initialization which takes too much code.  You need to refactor your code.